# How to Add Social Media Links as Icons in WordPress Theme Footer?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a custom WordPress theme and I'd like to add social media links with corresponding icons in the footer of my website. I want these icons to be clickable links to my social media profiles. But it's not working.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I added the necessary HTML code to the **`footer.php`** file to create the icon links.

However, the icons aren't working as expected, and I'm unsure if there's something wrong with my code or if I'm missing a step. Can someone guide me on the correct way to achieve this?

Here's the code snippet I've added to my **`footer.php`** file:

```
<footer/>
 <div class="social_link">
                        <ul class="list-inline social_links">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company" class="text-reset me-2"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook social_icon"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" class="text-reset me-2"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin social_icon"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" class="text-reset me-2"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter social_icon"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="text-reset me-2"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram social_icon"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
<footer/>
```

I'd appreciate any insights or corrections that could help me achieve the desired result. Thank you!

Comment: Apart from the typo in your `<footer>` tag, there is nothing obvious wrong with the code you gave us, so we can't see the problematic code to help you fix the problem. Also, please edit your question clarify what you mean by "the icons aren't working as expected"... what exactly is not working? e.g. are the icons not appearing where you want them / the wrong size / not appearing at all / not clickable / going to the wrong url etc.? We are unable to help without knowing what we're trying to fix and seeing the relevant code (including CSS if that is the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the closing tags for your footer. Make sure you have an opening '**< footer >**' tag instead of '**< footer/ >**' and a closing '**< /footer >**' tag to properly encapsulate the content within your footer.

Additionally, ensure that the FontAwesome classes for the icons (like **'fa-brands fa-facebook'**, **'fa-brands fa-linkedin'**, etc.) are correctly defined and available in your theme.

If you're still facing issues, you might want to check your browser's developer console for any JavaScript errors that could be affecting the functionality.

Overall, your approach seems correct, so verifying these details should help you achieve the desired result.

Comment: The footer tag is my spelling mistake...I apologize for this silly mistake... my font-awesome icons work correctly as well. lastly, I can't find any console error...is there any other way to link the icon?. By the way, thanks for your reply.